# Is $F$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ separable?

Tags: group-theory, extension-field, quotient-group, group-extensions, separable-extension

I want to determine whether the extension $F$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is separable, where:
$$F=\mathbb{F}_2(x)[t]/ \langle t^2+t+1 \rangle \quad \mbox{and} \quad \mathbb{F}_2 \mbox{ is the finite group with } 2 \mbox{ elements }  \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$

So far, I've worked out that $E=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/ \langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$ is separable over $\mathbb{F}_2$ by checking that for every $\alpha \in E$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ is separable. I was able to do this because $|E| = 2^2=4$, but $|F| = \infty$ and therefore I can't use this method anymore. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there not a theorem which says that if $\alpha$ is separable over $K$ then $K(\alpha)$ is separable?

Comment: wait, when you say $\mathbb{F}(x)$ in the first sentence, do you mean the fraction field of a polynomial ring in one variable, or do you mean $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how I would do it, but it seems to be the sort of argument you are asking for.

A general element $\alpha$ of your field $F$ is $f(x)\bar{t}+g(x)$. If $f=0$ this element lies in $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ and so is separable. If $f\not=0$ then the minimal polynomial $m(Y)$ of $\alpha$ is
$$
Y^2+f(x)Y+f(x)^2+f(x)g(x)+g(x)^2
$$
whose derivative wrt $Y$ is (the invertible) $f(x)$, so that the highest common factor of $m$ and $m'$ is $1$. Hence $m$ does not have repeated roots and so $\alpha$ is separable.

Comment: I hope $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are rational power series or Laurent power series over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: $f,g\in\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is surely clear?

Comment: Ok, How did you get $m(Y)$ ? Can you please write it ?

Comment: Crunch it out for yourself and see if $m(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: I looked at $\alpha^2$, $\alpha$, $1$ and found the coefficients to make $\alpha^2+p(x)\alpha+q(x)=0$. I knew it was degree $2$ because I was dealing with the case $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{F}_2(x)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much for your answer. I don't fully undestand how you deduce that $m'(Y)=f(x)$, I think it sould be $2Y+f(x)$

Comment: @ancientmathematician, May be I am not getting it.  why you wrote $\bar t$  but not $t$ ? Second, I didn't see how $m(\alpha)=0$. Here $\alpha=f(x) \bar t+g(x)$ and in order $m(\alpha)=0$, we must have to show that $m(\alpha)$ is a multiple of $(t^2+t+1)$. How did you do that ? Please elaborate your answer

Comment: @kubo : $2=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @Masmath : $\bar{t}$ is the coset of $t$ in the quotient modulo $t^2+t+1$. What do *you* get for $m(\alpha)$? I get $0$.